# couchbase python SDK long live connection

Tags: python, couchbase

Am using this code

```
from couchbase.cluster import Cluster
from couchbase.cluster import PasswordAuthenticator
cluster = Cluster('couchbase://localhost')
authenticator = PasswordAuthenticator('username', 'password')
cluster.authenticate(authenticator)
cb = cluster.open_bucket('bucket-name')

while True :
   cb.get('key1').value
```

to do > 500 op/seconds over 24 hours.

After 10mins, the connection is lost and proccess is killed.
Suppose SDK has some memory issues....

How to solve the issue ?
Do I need to reset the connection ?

ORIGIN found:
   cb.get('key1').value returns a python list of 100,000 string.
   This query is done 100 times a second.
   --> Python interpreter increases OS allocation (even we use gc.collect),
       and ends up being killed by OS .

--> Python problem of managing large list + realloc OS memory.

Comment: Is there an error message in the log that indicates why the connection is being lost?

Comment: killed on the bash output screen.

Comment: I'm talking about logging like so: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/python/collecting-information-and-logging.html

Comment: Could you run your application under valgrind and put report here?

Answer (score 0):

ORIGIN found:

```
 cb.get('key1').value returns a python list of 100,000 string. 
 This query is done 100 times a second. 
 --> Python interpreter increases OS allocation (even we use gc.collect)
 And ends up being killed by OS .
```

--> Python problem of managing large list + realloc OS memory.

Reference:

https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html